# Tz date format to human readable format

Tags: linux

I have a log file containing date and time in the format below

> 2016-11-03T00:00:18.976926847Z

I would like to change this to more human readable formate, like 2016-11-03 00:00:18

Comment: I am using this format on RHEL.
export NLS_DATE_FORMAT="YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS"

Answer (score 2):

If you have `GNU date` just do

```
$ date -d "2016-11-03T00:00:18.976926847Z"
Thu Nov  3 05:30:18 IST 2016
```

where the `-d` flag as per the `man` page

```
-d, --date=STRING
    display time described by STRING, not 'now'
```

and to format it as you need add the custom format `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`

```
$ date -d "2016-11-03T00:00:18.976926847Z" +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
2016-11-03 05:30:18
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo 2016-11-03T00:00:18.976926847Z|sed 's/T/ /;s/\..*$//'                   
2016-11-03 00:00:18
```

Comment: Ok this works fine, now is there a way, where I loop through a csv file with Column A with dates in 2016-11-03T00:00:18.976926847Z and output the csv file with formated date.